# how to handle exceptions in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

I am creating a program in which a user can search and add their desired order. The problem that I'm facing now is that when I throw the exception, the program does not read the exception so that the user will know if the id that is entered is on the database or not. I will provide the code snippet of the program that I'm working on.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as text not a screenshot

Comment: I would suggest you put a breakpoint and see what is actually happen. I'm pretty sure you'll notice that there's no exceptions happening and that you are just not entering the while loop. Also, read up on sql injection, you have a security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems**

1. Your code will **not** throw an error if the `item_code` does not exist in your database. It will simply not enter the `while` loop.
2. This is not the proper use of an exception. It is not an error if the record is not found. The proper way of checking if the `item_code` exists is a check if the datareader has results.
3. You **must** properly defend yourself again SQL injection. By concatenating the sql query you are opening yourself up to a whole host of problems. For example, if a user maliciously enters the following text, it will delete the entire Products table: `';DROP TABLE Products;-`
4. You are not disposing of the `OleDbConnection` or the `OleDbCommand` objects correctly. If an exception occurs, your code will not run the `Dispose()` method. This can cause you to quickly run out of resources.

**Solutions**

1. You should check if the `dataRead` has any rows. If it does not, *then* you can alert the user via javascript. Like so:

   ```
   If dataRead.HasRows Then
       //READ DATA
   Else
       //ALERT USER
   End If
   ```
2. Solution #1 address Problem #2 as well
3. Use a parameterized query. The .NET framework will prevent these kinds of attacks (SQL Injection).

   ```
   selectProductQuery = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE item_code = @item_code"
   ...
   newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("item_code", txtItemCode.Text);
   ```
4. Wrap all objects that implement `Dispose()` in a using block. This will guarantee everything is properly disposed of, whether an error is thrown or not.

   ```
   Using newCon As New OleDbConnection(....)
       Using newCmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(...)
           ...
       End Using
   End Using
   ```

To be perfectly honest, there is quite a bit "wrong" with your code, but this should get you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
Response.Write(<script>alert('The ...')</script>)
```

Needs to be (note the quotes):

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The ...')</script>")
```

Same for the other one at the top, but I dont think that will fix your overall problem.

Instead, use javascript like this:

```
if(!alert('Whoops!')){window.location.reload();}
```

to pop up an alert box and then reload the page after they click on the button.